# Jumping to next closest element

Tags: algorithm

Given an array of N elements, numbered from 1 to N. The ith element has value V[i]. Also all elements are distinct.

To move from ith to jth element we need to spend a cost of |i-j|.
But we can jump from ith to jth element only if :

1. j is not closer than K positions from key i (i.e. j should not be in the range [ i-K+1, i+K-1 ]).
2. V[j] < V[i].

Each element may have 0 or more elements that can be jumped to.

We need to find the summation of cost required to go from each element i to the closest element that can be jumped after it. If there is no next element to which we can jump for a element i, then consider its cost as 0.

Example : Let N=5 and K=1 and array be [3,5,4,2,1] then here answer is 6

Explanation :

```
The next jumping elements for:
1 is { }. Closest=none, so cost = 0
2 is { 1 }. Closest=1, so cost = 1
3 is { 1 , 2 }. Closest=2, so cost = 3
4 is { 1 , 2 , 3 }. Closest=2, so cost= 1
5 is { 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 }. Closest=3 or 4, so cost = 1
```

Total cost is 6

I know a brute solution that will run in O(N^2). But 1 <= N <= 2 * 10^5 and 1 <= K,V[i] <= N. So what can be better way to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

By using binary tree to store indexes you can reduce it from O(n^2) to O(n^lg(n)).

Start with empty tree T, iterate from 1 -> N. On each step, when you enter new index in tree, you can also get closest index.

Comment: You'll have to provide more explanation than that. I don't see how using the the binary tree will solve the problem.

Comment: Start with empty tree T. Now insert first index. As there are no other indexes the closes distance is 0. Next, insert 2nd index. Now when inserting it, compare it to all elements on path of insertion and choose the smallest value.

Comment: I'm not sure that will work. You can't guarantee that the index that is K distance from the item being inserted will be on the insertion path.

Comment: Closest index will definitely be on insertion path, just give it a thought. When you are inserting something in binary tree, you are always moving towards closest possible value, therefore it is impossible to miss closes index.

Comment: Yes, but the first condition says that the the one he's looking for "can't be closer than K positions from key." As a result, I don't think your algorithm will work when K > 1.

Comment: You are correct. It can still be done with binary tree then, but will be a bit trickier.